# Copying java keystore

Tags: java, ssl, keystore

I have a valid keystore on my local development machine, which contains a certificate for accessing a webservice via HTTPS.

I access this keystore in my project via:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.truststore", "C:\\<workspaceprojectPath>\\SIPkeystore\\truststore.jks"); // sollte wohl auch ohne Keystore klappen
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:\\<workspaceprojectPath>\\SIPkeystore\\SIPkeystore.jks");  
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "SECRET");
```

Now I want to access that certificate from another project. There I provide the same (full) path to the keystore in the other (local) project directory.

Apparently the path is still found by the jvm and the property is being set, but on accessing the web service I get the same error message as if I hadn't added the keystore at all.

When trying run the application I get a

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:   
     sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid 
     certification path to requested target
```

Is there a possibility to copy an existing keystore? This will be important also, when we deploy the application to our server. The application will run as stand-alone jar. (no web server)

**EDIT:**
Ok, copying the keystore does not seem to be the problem, as I am able to run the original application while using a local copy of the original keystore files. It seems like it is a configuration issue.

Comment: Are you sure you connect to the same web service in your second project?

Comment: Are you sure the signing cert was added to the trustStore and not the keyStore? (Just asking because I've done this and wondered why it didn't work!)

Comment: @Devon_C_Miller: I added it to the keystore. I thought the truststore was just there to ensure that the keystore is trusted. Could you please elaborate further. Thanks

Comment: The keystore holds any private keys and corresponding certificates. The truststore holds the certificates of authorities that are trusted to sign certificates. Also, if you add a certificate without the -trustcacerts flag it will not be considered when trying to build the PKIX path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if Web service doesn't require client certificate (i.e. that you introduce yourself) there's no need for keystore - you only need truststore.

It could be that other project cannot access truststore, so just for exercise, try to open `C:\<workspaceprojectPath>\SIPkeystore\truststore.jks` there and read first few bytes. If you succeed, it means that the other project has some other truststore set as default, so in that case try:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore"));
```

Also, bear in mind that Java is case-sensitive, and you specified `javax.net.ssl.truststore` property instead of `javax.net.ssl.trustStore`. Try fixing this also.

Comment: I have created a new truststore, containing the CA certificate. I then specified javax.net.ssl.trustStore and ...trustStorePassword (without specifying any keystore) and it worked like a charm from both projects in my eclipse (absolute path to the same truststore in both projects) Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a possibility to copy an existing keystore?

Yes.  From the file system perspective it is just a file.

I imagine that the problem is one of the following:

- The relevant properties are not correctly set in the other project.
- The other JVM cannot find the keystore file (e.g. because of chrooting or some such)
- The other JVM doesn't have the required permissions to access/read the keystore file.
- The read access is being blocked by (for instance) SELinux.

Comment: Thank you for your answer: I copied the above code from project 1 to project 2, so the properties should be set accordingly. I am going to check that. Well, the JVM is the same as for Project 1. When setting the properties to a noneexisted path, I get a `keystore not found`exception. I run both projects from eclipse. They are in the same workspace. That is the strange thing.

Answer (score 0):

The valicert class 3 CA certificate is not in your default truststore (which is probably the cacerts file in your JRE lib/security directory, but see the [JSSE documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#X509TrustManager) for the full story).

I think you should create your own truststore file (which can be a copy of the cacerts file) and add the valicert root ca to this. Then point to this file with the javax.net.ssl.trustStore system property.